# Set the row and column of widget in QT grid layout using property window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have added two labels and two textboxes in QT grid layout. These are all in vertical layout. I want to make it in 2x2 grid. I want to set the row and column of widget using its property window or style sheet (not using code).

I can see row and column in xml view of ui window but not in property window of my form. Where can I find the row and column property of a particular widget inside a gridlayout.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this is your intent

[image]

You can’t control a widget's row/col in a grid layout using the properties tab. The only way is to drop the widget into a specific position in the layout (see the blue vertical line)

[image]

Drop your widgets there.

Or, outside of the Designer, you may edit the `.ui` file and set the "row"/"column" values of the grid.

Comment: Yes you are right in this manner we can do this but I want to ask is there anyway after placing we can change the row column. After placing its very difficult to change the widget row and column